# PHP - Check difference between 2 different time format

Tags: php, laravel

I'm saving an updated_at time in the database which is being handled by laravel.

I want to check the difference between a field updated_at value and Now time in minutes .

This is how i get current time :

```
$now = time();
```

This is my echo results :

```
UPDATED AT : 2017-09-10 13:14:29
TIME NOW : 1505051247
```

Any idea how to check the time between these 2 values by minutes.

Thanks

Comment: Laravel uses [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) so you should do `Carbon::now()` to get current time instead of what you're doing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Laravel so use power of [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference)

```
$updated_at = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2017-09-10 13:14:29');
$timeNow = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp(1505051247); // but you should use \Carbon\Carbon::now()

$diffInMinutes = $updated_at->diffInMinutes($timeNow);
dd($diffInMinutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Carbon`

```
use Carbon;

$time_now = Carbon::now();
$updated_at = Carbon::parse('2017-09-10 13:14:29');
$differenceInMinutes = $updated_at->diffInMinutes($time_now);
```

Hope it's helpful.